# What's the point of !! in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I was just trawling through the QUnit source code (1.12.0) and came across a line that confused me. I've done a bit of googling and haven't been able to come up with a reason for it.

Source: http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.js line 520

```
result = !!result;
```

A similar thing appears further on in the code, except instead of storing the result in itself, it's storing the double negated variable in JSON.

Source: http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.js line 957

```
result: !!result
```

As ! negates, I assume !! will negate then negate again, thus ending up with exactly what you started with. In which case, what is achieved by setting a variable equal to itself, negated twice? (Or in the latter example, returning itself negated twice instead of just returning itself.)

Comment: pretty much casts the argument to boolean

Comment: It's to check a [truthy](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/truthy-falsey/) value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!!` is used to convert the value to the right of it to its equivalent boolean value.

Also check this related [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript).